# How Does QuickBlox work?

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

This is gonna be my first app in android. I have add some experience coding in java and C++. Now I need to create an app and i would like to add chat functionality similar to Whatsapp. Could this be done with Quickblox ( Also push notifications are needed for Google cloud Messaging)... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all features that you will need for your app such as chat, push notification, locations, create your own custom structure of data. All this modules will help You with your app. You can find all examples which demonstrate features of QuickBlox platform in this repository (https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk)
More recently, our mBaas system provide video chat that help you to add more cool things in your app (https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-android)